# HTML form attribute "name" not getting defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Below is the sample code in my JSP page:

```
<form name = loginform method = post action="">
<table class=registerTable>
<tr>         
    <td>Username:</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input name=user type=text class=usnm required size=28 maxlength=35 autocomplete="off" onblur="validateUser()" onkeyup="checkUsernameAvailability(this.value)"><br></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <span id = uerrmsg class = error></span><br></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When `onblur=validateUser()` is called the following code executes:

```
function validateUser(){
if(loginform.user.value.length<5){
    document.getElementById("uerrmsg").innerHTML="minimum 5 characters";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById("uerrmsg").innerHTML="";
    return true;
    }
}
```

Error Console in FF gives the following error

> loginform is not defined

Please help me on this.

PS: Above code works in all other browser.

Comment: Perhaps the space between the '=' and 'loginform' is tripping FF up? I'd say the other browsers are actually being really generous by ignoring that.

Comment: You really really should add quotes around your attributes.

Comment: @TravisJ `name` is not deprecated for `input` elements.  See: [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10]).

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  It works for me in FF8.0.

Comment: @cheeken Where does it say that name is not deprecated for input elements? `"Note that in XHTML 1.0, the name attribute of these elements is formally deprecated, and will be removed in a subsequent version of XHTML."` That was in regard to HTML 4 as well, and we are now on HTML 5.

Comment: @TravisJ "These elements," in reference to those noted at the beginning of that section: `a`, `applet`, `form`, `frame`, `iframe`, `img`, and `map`.

Comment: That link is 10 years old.  See a full list of supported HTML element attributes from w3.org here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global

Comment: @TravisJ If you prefer the HTML5 spec. (draft), look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element).  You can see explicitly that `name` is an allowable attribute.  (Your link only describes attributes that apply to all elements; we've already established that `name` is deprecated for some elements.)

Comment: @all thanks. FF is not too generous as other browsers are!

PS: "name" attribute is not deprecated. Eclipse does not five me warning about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use input.getAttribute("name") to get name attribute of an input.
This works for almost all browsers.

By the way, if you use getElementById, you must populate "id" field of input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `document.loginform`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the form for this.
First give your input an id: id="user". Then you can access it using document.getElementById(), as you do with the  element. something like this:

```
document.getElementById("user").value.length
```

Also, your code is very non-standard, for eg you should not put a " " (space) between the attribute (or it's value) and the = sign. And the attributes' values should be within quotes (Look at the source code of this page, for example).